# JLabel does not appear in JFrame when implemented in separate classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to add a JLabel to my JFrame. I have implemented them in separate classes but when I run the code, I cannot see my label.

It worked well when I implemented both frame and label in the `App` class.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        this.setSize(420, 420); 
        this.setTitle("First Java GUI");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    public MyLabel() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Welcome");
    }
}
```

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MyFrame frame1 = new MyFrame();
        MyLabel label1 = new MyLabel();

        frame1.add(label1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you extending `JLabel`?  You're not adding any new functionality to the class and are, instead, causing yourself issues.  I would consider a builder or factory pattern over extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in `MyLabel` class. If you extend it, just add constructors. But you in your constructor create another label, that is not added to frame. So, correct version is:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    
    public MyLabel(String text) {
        super(text);
    }
    
    public MyLabel() {
    }
}
```

And after it:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MyFrame frame1 = new MyFrame();
        MyLabel label1 = new MyLabel("Welcome");

        frame1.add(label1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    public MyLabel() {
        super();
        setText("Welcome");
    }
}
```

is what you need. You hide your code inside another `JLabel` which is *not* your subclass. It sort of begs the question though: why are you creating a subclass? Why not just use a `JLabel` right off?